# set background color with a background image

Tags: html, css, image

I have a background image set using an id and i want the body's background to be black so while the background image loads the user will see black instead of the default while background color.

When i set the background to black in the body through CSS the background image cant be seen anymore, it has gone behind the black background, how can i make the image show on top and the black behind the image?

( Ive tried setting the z-index to 200 or something but that didnt work so i put it back to -100 where i want it )

HTML:

```
<img src="Background_optimized_more.jpg" name="fsbg" width="2022" height="1460" id="fsbg">
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background: #000;   
}

#fsbg {

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -100;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1040px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an `<img>` node for a background image instead of the CSS `background-image` property?

Comment: You don't have a *background image* anywhere in that code.

Comment: Why do you want `z-index: -100;`? Do you really have 99 other instances of z-index between -100 and 0?

Comment: @esqew I folowed a turial to have a background image that adjusts to different screen sizes and this is what they showed and it works for me

Comment: @TylerH so it was the at the very back it could be any value doesnt matter i just wanted it at a minus value, the z-index isnt the cause of it

Comment: @TilwinJoy i do, its an <img> styled with CSS

Answer (score 0):

`background` will take precedence over more specific rules. Try using `background-color` instead:

```
background-color: #000;
```

Then, to specify the background image, use `background-image`.

Comment: then my background image isnt responsive

Comment: It is if you use `background-size: cover`?

Answer (score 0):

Apply your background image to your body with CSS and specify a colour with it. In this example, there is a black background colour beneath my background image. `background-size: cover;` ensures that your background scales nicely.

Read more [on background-size here.](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Read more [about CSS backgrounds here.](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background)

---

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/74JVJ/1/)

CSS

```
body {
    background: #000 url('http://www.placehold.it/500') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: That does seem like it would work but this way my background image is not responsive, i need it to be responsive that is why i made an id to style my background image. any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by responsive? Using `background-size` The image is scaled to the viewport.

Answer (score -1):

your `z-index` is on `-100`

this wil make the image go behind your background.

set is above 0

Comment: `z-index` values do not affect stacking when the elements are not siblings. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context